# Remember the nice value in Linux

Tags: linux, nice

On Linux, how to make the processes remember their `nice` between starts ?

For XP+ you can use [Prio](http://www.prnwatch.com/prio.html) to remember the priority and also the IO priority on VISTA+. However, on Linux, and only for running via terminal, I've had to create a command in `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Changing a shortcut works too, but you can't create endless count of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really think you can. I have a shortcut / bash script that `renice`'s itself and then launches the executable associated with it. I generally don't have too many processes that I have to renice (just my minecraft server), so I haven't found it to be too big of an issue.

```
#!/bin/sh
renice 4 -p $$
mono McMyAdmin.exe
```

and then I just run the script instead of the executable I usually would.

Comment: Accepted as an answer, for the script. Someone really should make something like Prio. Can't be that hard for a Linux coder.

Answer (score 0):

For the few commands you may run frequently that you want niced, you can alias the command in your `.bashrc` file.  This can be overridden if you want to run without nice.

In years of working with Unix and Linux, I haven't needed to run many programs using nice.  Most of those I don't want niced all the time.  The scheduling model on Unix works well in most cases without it.

Most of the programs that I do want niced all the time have a mechanism already.  I run BOINC to share spare CPU cycles with various research projects.  It is automatically niced, and has options to stop working when there is a heavy load.

There are some batch jobs I want niced.  They tend to be scripted, so it is easy to add the nice command to the beginning of the command line.

If I do fire up a lot of processes at once, I may renice some processes.  Now that ionice is available, I have had occasion to use it on a running process, but it is not something I routinely do.